# Как сделать фильтр текста по регулярному выражения передаваемому как аргумент?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

> Необходимо реализовать консольную программу, которая бы фильтровала поток текстовой информации подаваемой на вход и на выходе показывала лишь те строчки, которые содержат слово передаваемое программе на вход в качестве аргумента.
>
> В качестве аргумента может быть задано не конкретное слово, а регулярное выражение

Как это выполнить?

*в регулярных выражениях я недостаточно хорошо соображаю.*

Comment: Убрал из вопроса все лишнее, не относящееся к делу и дал нормальное название. Учтите

Comment: и в чем смысл минусов к вопросу?

Answer (score 0):

Регулярное выражение – это строка, последовательность символов/Регулярные выражения могут использоваться для поиска, редактирования и манипулирования текстом. Шаблон, определенный регулярным выражением, может совпадать один или несколько раз, или не совпадает с данным текстом.Например можете использовать Класс Java Matcher имеет много полезных методов

Comment: К примеру со Сканнера с помощью метода nextLine если передать аргумент регулярное выражение - то программа выводит на консоль буквально ничего. Но если передать тот же выражение не со Сканнера а просто на отдельном String поле присвоить - то работает. 2-ая проблема: в работающем случае, к примеру, при регулярного выражения \r в стринг поле "kol\rpod" выводится только часть "pod" а где часть "kol" уходит? Насчет класса Matcher - пока не рассмотрел, содержания класса немаленькое. Надо время найти покопаться в методах.